# Symfony entity form with dynamic fields from another entity

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, silex

### Question:

Consider following **Order** form:

```
META DATA:

Title:       [________]

REQUIREMENTS:

What size?  [_] Small    [_] Medium    [_] Large
What shape?  [_] Circle    [_] Square    [_] Triangle
.
.
.
```

How can I generate the form?

### Constraints:

- `size` & `shape` & `...` should be retrieved form another entity named: `Requirement`.

### What I think:

**Order**

```
Class Order
{
    private $title;

    //OneToMany(targetEntity="Requirement", mappedBy="order")
    private $requirements;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->requirements = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

**Requirement**

```
Class Requirement
{
    private $title;

    //ManyToOne(targetEntity="Order", inversedBy="requirements")
    private $order;

    //OneToMany(targetEntity="Selection", mappedBy="selections")
    private $selections;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->selections = new ArrayCollection();
    }

}
```

**Selection**

```
Class Selection
{
    private $title;

    //ManyToOne(targetEntity="Requirement", inversedBy="selections")
    private $requirement;
}
```

**OrderType**

```
class OrderType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'allow_extra_fields' => true
        ));
        $resolver->setRequired('em');
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $em = $options['em'];
        $requirements = $em->getRepository(Requirement::class)->findAll();

        $form = $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, array());

        foreach ($requirements as $requirement) {

            $args['label']         = $requirement->getTitle();
            $args['expanded']      = true;
            $args['multiple']      = true;
            $args['mapped']        = false;
            $args['class']         = Selection::class;
            $args['choice_label']  = 'title';
            $args['choice_value']  = 'id';
            $args['query_builder'] = call_user_func(function (EntityRepository $er, $requirement) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                        ->where('s.requirement = :requirement')
                        ->setParameter('requirement', $requirement)
                },$em->getRepository($args['class']), $requirement);

            $form
                ->add($requirement->getTitle(), EntityType::class, $args);

        }

        $form
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array(();

        return $form;
    }
}
```

### Problem:

This works nice and I can persist new `Order`s. The problem is with editing the `Order`, as

```
$form->createView()
```

while filling order `title` correctly, **would not update the selections** (checkboxes). I don't even know if this is the right way of doing this on Symfony. I don't know how can I refill selected checkboxes while rendering the edit entity form.

### Notice:

I don't think if [Symfony Form Collections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) is a good idea, as the requirements are changing in time and could not be hardcoded as `FormType`s, thus should be stored in database.

Comment: I think this can be done by setting a data option `$args['data'] = $requirement->getChoice()` If you need to do it automaticaly it can be handled in other form class `RequirementType`. And then you cycle and pass the Requirement object to it.

Comment: Well, I still don´t know if I understood the problem correctly, so I reexplain it so that my answer fits a question: __When reloading the form, the previous selected values are gone, right?__ Well thats because the selected choices don´t get stored anywhere: A `Requirement` has `$selections` but does not hold the selected `Selection` choice. So I would add a property `$selectedChoice` and change the formfield which name now is `$requirement->getTitle()` for each requirement to `selectedChoice` and map it (`mapped => true`) so that the form fills the `selectedChoice` property. Did that help?

Comment: No, that is not my problem. Just consider reading `Notice` section again, or the whole question, if you prefer to